# Add new file to existing review in reviewboard

Tags: git, review-board

I have this situation:
I've added not all files to reviewboard from last commit (using --include=)
But later I was asked to add a few more files (from same last commit) to this new review request.

Using 
    `rbt post -r <numberOfReview> -I <file>`
throws error: `There don't seem to be any diffs!`

Is there a way to do it at all? Or the only way is to post a new review request?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little old, but in case it helps someone else, you could always do the diff manually before posting it as an update to the same review request. I.e.

```
git diff --full-index revision_number -- all files to diff > newdiff.diff
rbt post -r numberOfReview --diff-filename newdiff.diff
```

The revision number will most likely be HEAD~1, but you could check the git log to be sure. Also, mind the --full-index on the diff, Reviewboard doesn't understand short indexes (which is what git produces by default.)